# Math syntax in Rust

Tags: rust

In Rust, it seems that the syntax for simple math expressions like `sin(x)+cos(y)*sqrt(z)` have to be written like `x.sin()+y.cos()*z.sqrt()`, which is weird, and anti-natural, and prone to errors with more complex expressions (exp, log, powers, etc.).

How is it possible to write math expressions the “classical” way? If not possible, why Rust is asking to write them that way?

Comment: It's because the methods are baked into the type : https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.sin - seems more natural to me - I have an angle - what do I want to do with it.. convert it to sin, cos, tan etc.

Comment: *which is weird, and anti-natural* - There is no "natural" way to write mathematical expressions; it's just a different convention than what you're used to. If you knew some math before you started programming, when you learned C you probably learned to write `asin(2*x*x - 3*x - 2)` instead of `sin⁻¹ (2x² − 3x − 2)`, right? (Or maybe not; depending on where and when you learned math, the conventions might have been different, which is also my point.)

Comment: The function notation only feels more natural than the method notation to you because you're used to one and not the other. Give the method notation a try, and you'll see that it's pretty natural too. People would be used to `sin(x)+cos(y)*sqrt(z)` in C++, `x.sin()+y.cos()*z.sqrt()` in Rust and `sin x + cos y * √z` in maths, but it's easy to switch. If you had a lot of maths to type, nothing would prevent you from defining free-functions à la C++ and use `sin(x)+cos(y)*sqrt(z)`.

Comment: I am a newbe on Rust (some days spent, to see if the parject of transfering sources is to be considered):
@trentcl. I see your point, but the fact is that I learned math well before programming :-)) and all the formulae speak of functions (like) y=f(x), ex: y=sin(x), so if I would find a language as close as possible of this, we could use our zillions of sources, to be simply copied and pasted in the rust source directly, instead of rewrite it like x.sin(). (I have math libraries -a lot- that I consider to transfer).

Comment: @mcarton. Thank for the idea. I tried it, but apparently I need to rename the functions (like sin1 or sin_), also is there a penalty due to the call from sin1->x.sin() ?

Comment: Please do not transform questions into answers via editing.  Instead, edit the question to make it more objective and focus on one question, and ping me (or other users) to cast a reopen vote on it.

Comment: `sin(x)+cos(y)*sqrt(z)` is weird and anti-natural and prone to errors. The natural syntax is obviously `(+ (sin x) (* (cos y) (sqrt z)))`. (This is tongue-in-cheek, but there are benefits to lisp sexps. It's very similar to [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). Your "natural" syntax is no more natural than another.)

Comment: Tone police aside, this is a valid question. I'm also baffled by this syntax.

Comment: I was looking for exactly this question and would vote for re-opening it. Personally, I would prefer the "classical" syntax, because reading the method notation `x.sin()` I would assume that the value of `x` is changed to the sine of it afterwards, which is not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, these methods are defined on the type. A possible alternative is to call the method directly, e.g:

```rust
f64::sqrt(25.0);
```

If you really want to, you can also bind it like so:

```rust
fn example_a(n: f64) -> f64 {
    let sqrt = f64::sqrt;

    sqrt(25.0)
}
```

```rust
const SQRT: fn(f64)-> f64 = f64::sqrt;

fn example_b(n: f64) -> f64 {
    SQRT(25.0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason; it helps a lot. Is there a possibility to remove the f64:: too ? I tried "use f64", and other things but unfortunately, no change. However, I succeed with "use libm::sin" to obtain ex: sin(x)... Is there a way to use all the functions in libm at once ? like sort of "use libm::all" or equivalent ?

Comment: @Hugo I have added some variations. Using the [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/vbP357), as of Rust 1.46, they seem to compile down to the exact same thing.

Comment: @Hugo: You can `use libm::*;`, or be more selective with e.g. `use libm::{sin, cos, tan};`.

Comment: @Hugo Note that using `libm` inhibits inlining and constant folding, so `libm::sin(10.0)` may be significantly slower than `f64::sin(10.0)`.

Comment: You can do it with consts too : `const sin:fn(f32) -> f32 = f32::sin;` or 
`const log:fn(f32) -> f32 = |x| f32::log(x, 10.0);` for example.